# All nodes the same color despite dataMap() function defining different colors

Tags: cytoscape.js

I want to use an attribute on my nodes, 'opinion' to map color of nodes. Opinions are between -1 and 1 and should be colored between red and blue, or something similar. The values and colors don't matter so much as the actual mapping.

It appears to be colors all nodes in the graph are being colored based on the value of the first node in the graph, rather than mapping for each individual node.

Have tried making my opinions positive integers in case cytoscape didn't get along with my floats and/or negative values, but the same thing still happens.

style

```
                selector: 'node',
                style: {
                    'background-color': 'mapData(opinion, -1, 1, red, blue)',
                    'label': 'data(id)'
                }
```

object example
{"data":{"id":"0","label":"0","opinion":-0.7262256301578913}},{"data":{"id":"1","label":"1","opinion":0.4885386255035229}},{"data":{"id":"2","label":"2","opinion":0.6359066785321656}},{"data":{"id":"3","label":"3","opinion":0.18255639864554474}}

This is working to make nodes darker based on 'opinion' but that's not awesome for a dark background.. Could make the background white and go from red to black, but I'd rather be able to use divergent colors like red & blue to show the difference between groups represented.

```
selector: 'node',
style: {
                    'background-color': 'white',
                    'background-blacken': function(ele){
                        return ele.data('opinion')
                    },
                    'label': 'data(id)'
                }
```